# File field not working in edit frame

Tags: experience-editor

I'm pretty certain the issue exists in previous versions too.

Steps to reproduce:
- Create a template with a "File" field in it (among other things)

- Create an item with that template - assign proper presentation details.
- Create an Edit Frame, and assign the "File" field to it (File fields are not directly editable in Experience editor so we need either a custom edit button or an edit frame. Behaviour is the same in both cases).
- Open the Edit frame and try to assign a value to the File field (try to select a media item by clicking on "Open File").
- You get an error:

```
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RunPipelines()
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.FieldEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: name
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse(String name)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.File.OpenFile(ClientPipelineArgs args)
```

Anyone know how to work around this?

Comment: I am having this same problem in SC9.3.  Did you ever find a reason why this is happening?

Comment: I am also ahving this issue in SC9.3 with a component with a file field added. Only happens in Experience Editor and not in Content Editor.
It seems to be because it can't parse the language that should be set in scLanguage (and is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have a quickfix for this, though this seems to be a Sitecore bug.

The quickfix is to edit the file:

> \sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\FieldEditor.aspx

and add this line after the other hidden inputs:

```
<input type="hidden" id="scLanguage" name="scLanguage" />
```

This fixes the isse. But it could seem that the placeholder:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="scLanguage" runat="server" />
```

Is where that field should be added.